# How to update text on application installation screen in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, installation

[image]I want to print some text on installation screen on android app. I can see application anme and version but i need to display more details.

Comment: What is "installation screen"?

Comment: When i click on apk in mobile to install it, the screen where installation progress is shown

Comment: That is not your screen. It is provided either by the OS or by your app distribution channel (e.g., the Play Store). You cannot modify it.

Comment: I don't want to modify, I just want to show some more text on this screen.

Comment: "I just want to show some more text on this screen" -- that would be modifying that screen. There is no option for you to do this.